# Test wcf service with SOAPUI not working

Tags: c#, wcf, soapui

I have a WCf Service which is working fine while consuming it with VS Application. But it is giving error(An error occurred when verifying security for the message.) while consuming with SOAP UI.

If i run WCF in VS below are the Request (working fine)

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/ITest/GetUserData</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:7b4aa2ac-4399-4e24-9ea7-b8f3a9c446b6</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <GetUserData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <EmployeeID>XXXX</EmployeeID>
    </GetUserData>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

But if i try to consume it with SoapUI below are the Request (not working)

```
POST http://localhost/ABC/Test.svc HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="http://tempuri.org/ITest/GetUserData"
Content-Length: 435
Host: localhost
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><wsa:Action>http://tempuri.org/ITest/GetUserData</wsa:Action></soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <tem:GetUserData>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:EmployeeID>XXXX</tem:EmployeeID>
      </tem:GetUserData>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: what error do you get? Have you mapped the `wsdl` with your SOAP UI?

Comment: I am getting this error "An error occurred when verifying security for the message.

Comment: browse to `http://localhost/ABC/Test.svc?wsdl`.You'll get the `wsdl` for this `WCF` service. Save it in local and create a new soap project and browse to the `wsdl` location, select it. SOAP UI will show all the opartions available under this service in the project window(left pane).

Comment: I already mapped the wsdl with soap ui.